# Is it possible to rename a onmicrosoft.com domain?

Tags: azure, dns, office365, subdomain

**The problem - got registered in business standard with a domain that I could not avoid.**

1. While I was applying for a discount I have accidentally created domains that I did not like.
   creation.onmicrosoft.com was my intended domain, but after some glitches, I ended up with creation6.onmicrosoft.com.
2. Further to this I have integrated creation.com and set up my office 365 mail.
3. I was informed by microsoft that I have to start from scratch and I have no idea how to delete the creation.onmicrosoft.com domain so that I can re-register from the beginning.

**The question**

Is it possible to do a switch of the onmicrosoft.com domain without the number as it looks really unprofessional in my share point.i.e. Switch from creation6.onmicrosoft.com to creation.onmicrosoft.com as this is an additional custom domain that I have registered?

The share point that I have from the domain (creation6.onmicrosoft.com) is really unsightly and not professional

**What I did** -

1. I called support - they said not possible, register from the beginning.
2. I tried deleting via Azure but it reads bad error. But I could not release the domain - creation.onmicrosoft.com
3. I did abit of research and found the Powershell method to rename but I am a Mac user.

Answer (score 0):

You can register and assign a custom domain instead of using the onmicrosoft.com domain. See [Add a domain to Microsoft 365](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/setup/add-domain?view=o365-worldwide) for more information about that.

Comment: Hi there, thank you for your reply. Lets say I have purchased creation.com domain, is it possible to change my share point name since I have a bought domain?